# enum on xcode5.1 beta 5

Tags: xcode, ios7

I usually define my enum in the header file.

```
enum{
    kSection1,
    kSection2
};
```

My program was working fine until Apple releases new Xcode version.  Suddenly my program crashes and I am suspecting this enum.  I am using this enum in many areas like below:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == kSection1) {
        ...
}
```

and this

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) int typeToAdd;
...
if (self.typeToAdd == kSection1) {
...
}
```

and this

```
if (ball.type == [NSNumber numberWithInt:kSection1]){
...
}
```

I am seeing some articles on 32-bit and 64-bit thing but it's hard to understand.  Am I still doing it correctly?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and relevant code referenced by the stacktrace?

Comment: Since that version of Xcode hasn't been released yet, you may do better asking on the Apple Dev Forums for beta releases.

Comment: What's the error message? Show the code relevant to the stack trace from the crash.

Comment: by default, enum values are of type int... if I compare it to an tableview indexpath.section, it's not going through because it is of type NSInteger (in this case long because of the 64-bit)... thus my comparison is already incorrect... i am heavily comparing the tableview section values to my enum variables (which are of type int) so it's causing several errors throughout my application...
is there a way to declare enum as type "nsinteger"?